# Get a button index using onClick method

Tags: android, class, button, return

So , I was not making my self clear. I'm having a little trouble trying to get a button index from a matrix.
I have this matrix bt[4][4], and each button has a value like this :
 btn11 = bt[0][0].
Now what I want to do is, whenever I click on a Button, I get it´s "cordinates".
Ex: **Bt11 would give [0] and [0]** .
Now the problems that I'm having:

1. I've set listeners to each button, but I can't implement a "onClick" method.
   Whenever I try to implement here "public class easy extends Activity" I get an error message.
2. Second problem, I don't know to get the cordinates from bt[x][y].

To sum it up. I want to set a onClick method so every time you click on a button you get it's [x][y] cordinates.
Here's my code:

```
public class easy extends Activity { //Can't implement OnClick Listener
    Button bt[][] = new Button[4][4];
    Button up;
    Button down;
    Button left;
    Button right;

    int listaTroca[] = new int[10]; // lista pra receber os valores de retorno da logica



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy);





        //Linha 1
        bt[0][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt11);
        bt[0][0].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        bt[0][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt12);
        bt[0][1].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        bt[0][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt13);
        bt[0][2].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        bt[0][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt14);
        bt[0][3].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        //--------------------- Linha 2
        bt[1][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt21);
        bt[1][0].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        bt[1][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt22);
        bt[1][1].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        bt[1][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt23);
        bt[1][2].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        bt[1][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt24);
        bt[1][3].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        //------------------------Linha 3
        bt[2][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt31);
        bt[2][0].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        bt[2][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt32);
        bt[2][1].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        bt[2][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt33);
        bt[2][2].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        bt[2][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt34);
        bt[2][3].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        //---------------------Linha 4
        bt[3][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt41);
        bt[3][0].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        bt[3][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt42);
        bt[3][1].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        bt[3][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt43);
        bt[3][2].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        bt[3][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt44);
        bt[3][3].setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        //----------------------FIM DECLARAÇÃO + OUVIDOS
        listaTroca = Logic.Logic_main(1,1,1);



    }

}
```

Comment: Try using `button.setTag(key, value)`. Then when onClick is called you can return the value using `v.getTag(key)`

Comment: You do not have a question in your post. What do you need / what's not working?

Comment: @Vucko Edited the question already. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what your question is here, but from what i understand you want a `View.OnClickListener()` on each button, and when the button is being clicked you want to do something right?

**EDITED**: I've edited the answer as the question was clarified in the comments below.

What you want to do, is simply iterate your `bt[][]` to find the right button, like so:

```
public class Easy extends Activity {

    Button[][] bt = new Button[4][4];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy);

        //Linha 1
        bt[0][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt11);
        bt[0][0].setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

        bt[0][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt12);
        bt[0][1].setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

        // ADD YOUR OTHER findViewByID

    }

    View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ButtonCoordinate bc = getButtonCoordinate(v);
            if (bc != null) {
                // You now have your button, and the coordinates
                Log.d("Easy", "Button.position[ x:" + bc.x + ", y:" + bc.y + " ]");
            }
        }
    };

    private ButtonCoordinate getButtonCoordinate(View v) {
        for (int x = 0 ; x < bt.length ; x++ ) {
            for (int y = 0 ; y < bt[x].length ; y++) {
                Button b = bt[x][y];
                if (v == b) {
                    return new ButtonCoordinate(x, y, b);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static class ButtonCoordinate {
        public final int x;
        public final int y;
        public final Button button;
        public ButtonCoordinate(int x, int y, Button button) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.button = button;
        }
    }

}
```

you just need to call `getButtonCoordinate(View)` which will return a `ButtonCoordinate` containing the `Button` and it's `x` and `y` coordinates in the `bt[][]`

Comment: I'm trying to get that index at the bt[x][y] , exemple : bt11 would return to a int list [0,0]

Comment: And ,  I need it to be a generic method. So when you click on any of those buttons (bt[x][y])  , you will get it's x and y value.

Comment: Ok, i get it now. I've edited my answer, and the code above should work for you now.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you sir